# Flutter returning a bad state when firebase firestore delete is initiated

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am using Firestore as a database in my Flutter app, and I am using a StreamBuilder to access the data. But, whenever I try to do a delete operation using a button press, Flutter always returns this error:

```
The following StateError was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state:
_StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>>#3bac1):
Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist
```

but then proceeds to delete the item. I am able to add, update and read all the items in the collection, but this error always appears whenever I try to delete them. How could I make the error stop appearing?

This is the widget where the error occurs (It's quite long, I know), but I have removed some parts because they weren't very applicable or useful in this issue.

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(widget.uid)
              .collection('passwords')
              .doc(widget.password['appName'])
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 0),
                      child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                        size: const Size.fromHeight(80),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: const Color(0xFF0C163F),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  const Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 14, 0, 0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Login:',
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding:
                                        const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 4, 0, 0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      snapshot.data!['login'],
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              const Spacer(),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  child: const Icon(
                                    Icons.copy,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(
                                        text: 
                                      snapshot.data!['login'],));
                                  },
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 0),
                      child: SizedBox.fromSize(
                        size: const Size.fromHeight(80),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: const Color(0xFF0C163F),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  const Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 14, 0, 0),
                                    child: Text('Password:',
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                                  ),
                                  FittedBox(
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                          18, 4, 0, 0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        snapshot.data![‘password’]
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                              const Spacer(),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  child: const Icon(
                                    Icons.remove_red_eye,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  onTap: () async {

                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  child: const Icon(
                                    Icons.copy,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(
                                        text: 
                                      snapshot.data!['password']
                             
                                    ));
                                  },
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 12, 20, 0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: const [
                          Text('URLs:',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 15)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 12, 5, 0),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!['url'].length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            List datalist = snapshot.data!['url'];

                            return Card(
                                child: ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                datalist[index],
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                            ));
                          }),
                    )
                    ,
                    const Spacer(),
                    Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 8, 12, 22),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
                            primary: const Color.fromARGB(255, 150, 13, 13),
                            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                          ),
                          child: const Text('Delete Password'),
                          onPressed: () async {
                              await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                  .collection('users')
                                  .doc(widget.uid)
                                  .collection('passwords')
                                  .doc(widget.password(appname))
                                  .delete();
                          },
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the Firebase Console view:

[image]

Comment: can you edit the question and show us what is there in widget?

Comment: sure, ill do that

Comment: I saw there is only one single document. is it possible to add more data inside the password collection? it looks like when you delete that one, and StreamBuilder will not find any data.

Comment: can you check this stackoverflow[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68607904/18265638) &[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63897960/18265638) once?

Comment: @SathiAiswarya i tried to implement both answers in the links you attached, but im still getting the same error. the button on press still manages to delete the item from firestore, but the error still appears.

Comment: @FredericChang, I thought of this before, but even after adding numerous documents to the collection, every time I try to delete a document, the error continuously appears.

Comment: can you try these [github](https://github.com/projectsforchannel/firebase_crud) given in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHf7NH2_gQs) and [link1](https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-firestore-database/)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya i added this new delete function for the button to use, but the error appears again.

Comment: @trashflutterdev I have provided an answer below to your question. Can you check if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting by manually passing those arguments. I think it is not possible to delete items within a builder by referencing widget arguments.To delete any document you must know it's ID or have a DocumentReference to it. For that you just need to know the userId

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
   .collection('users') 
   .doc(userId)
   .collection('favourites')
   .where('id', whereIn: [...])
   .get() 
   .then((snapshot) { 
     // ... 
   });
```

You may try deleting the snapshot using the following syntax

`snapshot.docs[0].reference.delete()`, where you can index into the object
or
`snapshot.docs.get()` where you can  use the getter function.

You can refer link[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68429571/delete-document-by-content-of-a-field-in-firestore-flutter) for Delete document by content of a field in Firestore and also may have a look at [firestore doc](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection)